# Migrate images form external source (not drupal) to Node Destination

Tags: 7, migrations

I want to migrate external database table (not of a drupal website) to node destination having the content type : `'company_profile'`
the migration is done except the image field witch has the machine name `'field_company_image'.`

this is the class :

```
class CompanyProfileMigration extends BaseMigration {
  public function __construct($arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);
    $this->description = t('Company Profiles.');      

    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
        array('uid' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'description' => 'ID.'
                )
            ),
        MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema(),
        'typo3'
    );


    // Connect to the remote $databases
    $query = db_select(TYPO3_DATABASE_NAME.TABLENAME, 'cp')
        ->fields('cp', $this->queryParams['company_profile']['fields'])
        ->orderBy($this->queryParams['company_profile']['order_field'], $this->queryParams['company_profile']['order_field_operator']);
    $query->condition('cp.fe_user', 0, '<>');

    // Define source and destination for migration
    $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('company_profile');

    // Make the mappings

    $this->addFieldMapping('uid', 'fe_user')->sourceMigration('SwMigrateFeUser');

    // field_company_image
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_company_image', 'image')
        ->sourceMigration('CompanyProfileImage');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_company_image:file_class')
        ->defaultValue('MigrateFileFid');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_company_image:language')
     ->defaultValue('de');

    $this->addFieldMapping('created', 'crdate');
    $this->addFieldMapping('changed', 'crdate');
    $this->addFieldMapping('status')->defaultValue(1);
    $this->addFieldMapping('promote')->defaultValue(0);
    $this->addFieldMapping('sticky')->defaultValue(0);
    $this->addFieldMapping('language')->defaultValue('de');

    $this->addFieldMapping('path')->issueGroup(t('DNM'));
    $this->addFieldMapping('comment')->issueGroup(t('DNM'));


    // Back to local database again!
    db_set_active('default');
  }

}
```

The class that import images is called `"CompanyProfileLogoMigration"` 
that's why I added the source migration when mapping the image field :

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_company_image', 'image')->sourceMigration('CompanyProfileImage');
```

And the migration of the image files are done succefully (I can see them inside `default/files` directory, also inside `"file_managed"` database table are succesfully inserted!)

But, when I edit the nodes I don't find the image field filled up (the table `"field_data_field_company_image"` is empty !)

How can I improve this class or what im missing to make this relationship working ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what value is logo, is it a file_id?

Comment: no it's the 'filename' exp: my_image_name.png

Comment: I think this is the problem, it should expect the id that you used in the images migration, look into the images migration mapping table and see what you use there.

Comment: the image mapping table is the same as the company profile table "tx_exinitjobexchange_profiles" , I get the name of the logo from this table, then search on it inside the 'source_dir' then it import them... So the ID of each image entry is the same ID of the companyProfile (they are in the same table)

Comment: try to use the id in your mapping and see how it goes: `$this->addFieldMapping('field_company_image', 'companyProfile_ID')
        ->sourceMigration('SwMigrateCompanyProfileLogo');`. Migration with look the companyProfile ID in the mapping table and return the Drupal file id. Give it a shot

Comment: unfortunately not working :( just tried it. I changed like this : $this->addFieldMapping('field_company_image', 'uid')->sourceMigration('SwMigrateCompanyProfileLogo'); . The uid field is the ID of each profile company like montionned in $this->map variable in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27428/discussion-between-sam2de-and-boussetta-moez).